# Space&NewLine Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming. My English is not good, sorry.

**~Problem statement~**

> You are the creator of the Olympic medalist table.The country names
>   and player names of gold, silver and bronze medalists are given in
>   order, so let's write the medals ("Gold", "Silver", "Bronze") in front
>   of each country name and player name.

I get an error like this:

```
> Main.java:18: error: illegal character: '\' 
> Main.java:18: error: not a statement There are multiple errors.
```

I want to output in this format.

```
  m_g n_g
  m_s n_s
  m_b n_b
```

There is a space between m_ ~ and n_ ~.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n_g = sc.next(); 
        String n_s = sc.next();
        String n_b = sc.next();

        String m_g = "Gold";
        String m_s = "Silver";
        String m_b = "Bronze";

        System.out.println((m_g +'\0'+ n_g)\r\n(m_s +'\0'+ n_s)\r\n(m_b +'\0'+ n_b));
    }
}
```

**Example:**
 Given input

```
Japan
Russia
China
```

*Expected output*

```
Gold Japan
Silver Russia
Bronze China
```

Comment: I am sorry if the form of the question is wrong.

Comment: What did you expect `'\0'` to do? Why it is even in there?

Comment: for the `\r\n` you will need to wrap it in double quotes (`"`) - also use double-quotes for concatenating the `String`s (instead of single quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\r\n is unquoted. No need of \0 - it is not c or c++.
Just print each country on a separate line using a separate statement. That would be consistent with the input and constant coding style you have above

```
 System.out.println(m_g + " " + n_g);
 System.out.println(m_s + " " + n_s);
 System.out.println(m_b + " " + n_b);
```

Comment: I thought it was simple. ARIGATO.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
 System.out.println(m_g +" "+ n_g + System.getProperty("line.separator") + m_s +" "+ n_s + System.getProperty("line.separator") +m_b +" "+ n_b);
```

or

```
System.out.println(m_g +" "+ n_g + "\r\n" + m_s +" "+ n_s + "\r\n" +m_b +" "+ n_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand you error message. You have an error on line 18 of your Main.java file.
That line is the one with:

```
System.out.println((m_g +'\0'+ n_g)\r\n(m_s +'\0'+ n_s)\r\n(m_b +'\0'+ n_b));
```

The problem is those \r\n without double quotes and +. It should look something like:

```
System.out.println((m_g +'\0'+ n_g) + "\r\n" + (m_s +'\0'+ n_s) + "\r\n" + (m_b +'\0'+ n_b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n_g = sc.next(); 
        String n_s = sc.next();
        String n_b = sc.next();

        String m_g = "Gold";
        String m_s = "Silver";
        String m_b = "Bronze";

         System.out.println((m_g +" "+ n_g)+"\n"+(m_s +" "+ n_s)+"\n"+(m_b +" "+ n_b));

      }
  }
```